# About an equality involving prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let two primes : $p_1$ and $p_2$. I have $\alpha$ and $\beta$ two rationals and $b$ an integer with
$$4b=-(\alpha+1)(p_1-p_2)=-(\beta+1)(p_1+p_2)$$
Thus
$$(\alpha-\beta)p_1=(\alpha+\beta+2)p_2$$
Is this sufficient to claim that $\alpha=\beta$ ? Is there a proof ? And if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ were integers ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

no.
$$ p_1 = 5; p_2 = 3; b = -2; \alpha = 3; \beta = 0.  $$
$$ p_1 = 7; p_2 = 3; b = -5; \alpha = 4; \beta = 1.  $$
$$ p_1 = 3; p_2 = 2; b = -5; \alpha = 19; \beta = 3.  $$
$$ p_1 = 5; p_2 = 2; b = -21; \alpha = 27; \beta = 11.  $$